# jQuery Deferred in combination with jQuery Mobile "pageshow" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, promise, deferred

I try to implement something similar to the example on the [jQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

In short:

- data is loaded (used for calendar and several other things)
- when the user first visits a jQuery Mobile page the calendar is initialized
- when both data is loaded and the calendar is initialized then something else happens

The issue:
when I open the page on another page other than "#overview" it stills triggers the $.when, even though the calendar event has not yet been triggered. When I switch to the "#overview" page, the .one event triggers correctly.

In the console:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
page: "#initial"
*** data received *and* calendar initialized
[Object, "success", Object] undefined
-------------------------------------------------------------
page: "#overview"
going to initialize calendar
```

The code that I have:

```
    var getData = $.getJSON("./testDeferredData.php");

    function initializeCalendar() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        $(document).one("pageshow", "#overview", function(event,ui) {
            console.log("going to initialize calendar");
            deferred.resolve("calendar initialized");
            return deferred.promise();
        });
    }

    $.when(getData, initializeCalendar() ).then(function(data,calendar) {
        console.log("*** data received *and* calendar initialized");
        console.log(data,calendar);
    });
```

I am new to Deferred and Promise, so it is quite possible I am making a silly mistake.
Suggestions?

Comment: Your `return deferred.promise()` is inside the event handler by mistake rather than the initializeCalandar function. The function returns undefined which is cast to an already resolved promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a argument which is not a deferred/promise object, it will be treated as resolved. So you have to return the promise object properly.

```
function initializeCalendar() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(document).one("pageshow", "#overview", function(event,ui) {
        console.log("going to initialize calendar");
        deferred.resolve("calendar initialized");    
    });
    //return promise object immediately
    return deferred.promise();
}
```